# Display CSS e HTML

Tags: html, css, div

Estou com um Problema para deixar meu menu em linha alguém poderia me informar o que estou fazendo de errado , obrigado !!!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */


#topo {
 background:url(../imagens/topo.png); 
 position:inherit;
 width:1024px;
 height:190px;
 border-bottom:none;
 margin:auto;

}

#logo {
 float:left;
 background:url(../imagens/logoc.png);
 position:relative;
 top:50px;
 left:230px;
 width:541px;
 height:133px;
}
 
#fundoinicial {
 background-image:url(../imagens/fundoof.png);
 width:1024px;
 height:1080px;
 margin:auto;
 
}

#menufundo {
 background:url(../imagens/menu.png);
 position:relative;
 width:1024px;
 height:30px;
 margin:auto;
}


#menu ul li a{
 font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size:20px;
 display:inline;
 line-height:30px;
 padding:50px;
    margin:40px 0 0 40px;
 color:#FFF;
 text-decoration:none;
 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Alfatec</title>

<link href="css/reset.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="css/estilo.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<style type="text/css">
body {
 background-image: url(../PLANILHAS%20CAIO/projeto/imagens/fundo.jpg);
}
{
 
</style>
</head>


<body>

   <div id="logo">
     </div>   <!--div final do logo-->
   <div id="topo"></div>   <!--div final topo-->  
   
    
            <div id="menufundo"><nav id="menu">
         <ul>            
          <li><a href="#">Página Inicial</a></li> 
          <li><a href="#">Quem Somos</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Áreas de Cobertura</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Serviços</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Fale </a></li>
      </ul>
       </nav>                
</div>                
   <div id ="fundoinicial">
</div>  
                    
                    
          
                   
                        
                 
                   
                        
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Voce pos o `a` como inline, mas o `li` continua mostrando linha a linha. Você teveria ter aplicado o inline (ou inline-block) no `li` em vez disso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use o display inline desta forma, abraços.

```
#menu ul li {
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado man consegui !!!! Abraços

Answer (score 0):

```css
#menufundo ul li{
    display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div id="logo">
     </div>   <!--div final do logo-->
   <div id="topo"></div>   <!--div final topo-->  
   
    
            <div id="menufundo"><nav id="menu">
         <ul>            
          <li><a href="#">Página Inicial</a></li> 
          <li><a href="#">Quem Somos</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Áreas de Cobertura</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Serviços</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Fale </a></li>
      </ul>
       </nav>                
</div>                
   <div id ="fundoinicial">
    </div>
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado consegui !!!! Abraços